# SecureCRT: vim not using maximum terminal window size

Tags: vim, secure-crt

No matter what the size of the SecureCRT window, vim's screen area remains constant. If I maximize SecureCRT, vim continues to only occupy a portion of the terminal.

I have fiddled with the obvious setting choices but have been unable to get vim to adjust to the width of the terminal window.

It DOES work when using ConEmu.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try explicitly setting the size from within Vim with `:set lines=... columns=...`.

Comment: Thanks but yes, tried that.

Comment: and then you should reconnect to take effect~